# pkFactory: db.options?.pkFactory ?? utils_1.DEFAULT_PK_FACTORY,^ SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at Module._extensions..js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, syntax-error

getting error like this when i import mongoose

`pkFactory: db.options?.pkFactory ?? utils_1.DEFAULT_PK_FACTORY,  ^  SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)  Node.js v18.17.0`

this is server.js file

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {readdirSync} from "fs";
const morgan = require("morgan");
require("dotenv").config();
//create express app
const app = express();

// //db
// mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
//   // userNewUrlParser:true,
//   // useFindAndModify:false,
//   // useUNifiedTopology:true,
//   // useCreateIndex:true,

// })


//apply middlewares

app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

//you can use your own middleware like this
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("this is my own middleware");
  next();
});

//route
//it is importing whole fs module but we are using the readdireSync() function only
//so we can imort the readdireSync() by destructuring method
//so we will import only this function only
// import readdirSync like this import {readdirSync} from "fs";
readdirSync('./routes').map((r)=>{
  app.use('/api',require(`./routes/${r}`))
  });

//server port
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
// start listen to our server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server is running on port : ${port}`);
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYMEH.png)

its my package.json file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Jzd.png)

when i uncomment mongoose import it working fine ? why ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVfp2.png)

i tried to connect mongodb some where  i found add `"type":module` somewhere found write file name with   `.mjs`
and somewhere different `remove -r esm` from package.json and somewhere different but anything not working   for me please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with local MongoDB and MERN project, but fixed with the following method:

1. Most probability the problem is in the mongoose version (I just downgraded it)
2. make sure .env file should be: (Change)

```js
DATABASE_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDB to
```

```js
DATABASE_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/exampleDB
```

3. Modify it the db connection code like https: [**linkedin artical**](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:share:7094665190855651330/)